# Removing specific strings from strings in a file

Tags: string, bash, awk

I want to remove specific fields in all strings in a semi-colon delimited file.

The file looks something like this :-

```
texta1;texta2;texta3;texta4;texta5;texta6;texta7
textb1;textb2;textb3;textb4;textb5;textb6;textb7
textc1;textc2;textc3;textc4;textc5;textc6;textc7
```

I would like to remove positions 2, 5 and 7 from all strings in the file.

Desired output :-

```
texta1;texta3;texta4;texta6
textb1;textb3;textb4;textb6
textc1;textc3;textc4;textc6
```

I am trying to write a small shell script using 'awk' but the code is not working as expected. I am still seeing the semicolons in between & at the end not being removed.

(Note- I was able to do it with 'sed' but my file has several hundred thousands of records & the sed code is taking a lot of time)

Could you please provide some help on this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most simply with `cut`:

```
cut -d \; -f 1,3-4,6,8- filename
```

or

```
cut -d \; -f 2,5,7 --complement filename
```

I think `--complement` is GNU-specific, though. The `8-` in the first example is not actually necessary for a file with only seven columns; it would include all columns from the eighth forward if they existed. I included it because it doesn't hurt and provides a more general solution to the problem.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html#cut-invocation) `--complement` is indeed a GNU extension. I just did `man` on Mac. It's not there.

Comment: The first one with the inverted set should work, though. That one's strictly POSIX-conforming.

Comment: Yes, I only printed the awk solution in the case, that he doesn't know the complement set; i.e. `1,3-4,6,8-`.

Comment: Thanks Wintermute ! Both the solutions work fine - Either can be used depending upon whether you have more positions to remove or to retain.

Answer (score 0):

I voted the answer by @Wintermute up, but if `cut --complement` is not available to you or you insist on using awk, then you can do:

```
awk -v scols=2,5,7 'BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS=";"} {
 split(scols,acols,","); for(i in acols) $acols[i]=""; gsub(";;", ";"); print}' tmp.txt
```

Comment: This deletes the first three columns because the indices of `acols` are 1, 2, and 3; you'll have to invert it first to check for removable columns with `i in acols`. It'll also have a problem if the input data contains empty fields. The first thing that comes to my mind to avoid that is to print the fields manually, as in `awk -v scols=2,5,7 -F \; 'BEGIN { n = split(scols, acols, ","); for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) rmcol[acols[i]] = 1 } { sep = ""; for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if(!rmcol[i]) { printf("%s%s", sep, $i); sep = FS } print "" }'`.

Comment: That's why I do `$acols[i]` instead of `i`. The OP did not mention empty fields.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Right, my mistake. Still, the empty field thing bothers me; it seems like something that shouldn't come totally unexpected to such a script. Perhaps mark it with something that can't appear in a line, such as a newline? I'm thinking `$acols[i] = "\n"; gsub(/;\n/, "")`, although that still has the caveat that it breaks if the first column is to be removed.

Comment: I guess one could just do `gsub(";;",""); gsub("^;",""); gsub(";$","")` for these special cases.